# How to export an array of objects that dynmically loaded in react

Tags: reactjs

I have TS file exporting an interface and an array of objects, items.ts:

```
export interface Item {
code: string
}

export const items: Item[]=[
{code: "code1"},
...
{code: "coden"}
}
```

And I have another TSX file importing {Item, items} and does some other logic. Now instead of hard-coded the items, I am trying to dynamically populate the items using following code:

```
export const items: Item[] = ()=> {
  const itemOptions = useItemOptions()
  const [itemCodes, setItemCodes] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!itemOptions.data) {
      return
    }
    
    setItemCodes(itemOptions.data)
  }, [])

  return itemCodes.map(code=>({code: code.display}));
}
```

The useItemOptions is a function imported from another ts. However, I am getting an error **Type '() => { code: any; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Item[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more**. Not sure what does this mean? I am new to React. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

To be clear, the following are the two functions being used:
useItemOptions:

```
export function useItemOptions() {
  const fetchItemCodes = useGetItemCodes()
  return useQuery(
    "items",
    async () => (await fetchItemCodes()).Data.ItemCodes,
  )
}
```

useGetItemCodes:

```
export function useGetItemCodes() {
  const api = api()
  const fetchAccessToken = useAccessToken()
  return useCallback(
    async () => await api.getItemCodes(await fetchAccessToken()),
    []
  )
}
```

Upated: I am not using items as a component, I just use it as an array of objects. I tried following:

```
function useItemOptions():Item[]{
  const fetchItemCodes = useGetItemCodes()
  const result =useQuery(
    "items",
    async () => (await fetchItemCodes()).Data.ItemCodes,
  )

  return result.data.map((itemcode)=>({code: itemcode.display}))
}

export const items=useItemOptions()
```

But I got invalid hook calls.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight exactly why you're seeing that error, it's because you're declaring the return statement incorrectly.

You're basically telling items to be an array of Item but then assigning a function to it. Instead, you'll want to declare it like this:

```
export const items = (): Item[] => {
  return [...];
};
```

This tells TS that you are declaring a function which has a return type of an array of items. Just a heads up, this isn't a valid React component. You'll want to return a React element instead of an array.

If you meant to have an array of items then you'll want to declare it like this:

```
export const items: Item[] = []
```

I'm not 100% sure what the end goal is, but it looks like you want to map some data from the server. Here's an example on how you could do that. This is making an assumption that you are using `react-query`.

```
function useItemOptions() {
  // Here we can use generics to tell useQuery what
  // sort of data we are expecting back
  return useQuery<Item[]>("items", async () => {
    // Mimic `ItemCodes` from the server
    // This comes back with the code as the `display` property
    // so we'll remap it here before it's sent out.
    const serverData = {
      Data: {
        ItemCodes: [{ display: "custom_code" }]
      }
    };

    return serverData.Data.ItemCodes.map((code) => ({ code: code.display }));
  });
}

const Items = () => {
  const { data } = useItemOptions();

  return (
    <ul>
      {data?.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.code}>{item.code}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Here's the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-mcclintock-t0vi3

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. My goal is instead of hard-coding the object array, I want to populate the items by calling the api. My question is I thought this line (return itemCodes.map(code=>({code: code.display})); ) returns an array of items, item[]. I modified the declaration of the return as export const items=(): Item[]=>{...}, the error was cleared. However, the tsx file where I import them, I have statement like items.filter((item)=>...), I got an error like Property 'filter' does not exist on type ()=>Item[].

Comment: Hi Dennis, I tried a different way. Can you check my updated? All the error cleared, but when I run it, I got invalid hook call.

Comment: @GLP you must use custom hooks in a React component. So when you call `export const items=useItemOptions()` it must be within a React component and not outside of it.

Comment: Check this codesandbox out. It takes your code into account. https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-night-z7po0?file=/src/App.tsx. If you're still experiencing problems, do you mind creating a codesandbox with your code?

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for your help. I think I didn't clearly understand how the lifecycle of a functional component and hooks work. I managed to pass the items as a prop, and then it worked. I marked the answer as it really helped steer me toward the right direction. Thank you.